# Can a transformer have no secondary stages?

Tags: transformer, ac, wiring, coil

While disassembling the power for the spindle of my hobby CNC mill, I came across something peculiar which I think warrants a question on this site.

The input is standard 220V AC.

- Phase 1 (brown) from source is fed directly to spindle phase 1.
- Neutral (blue) from source is fed to transformer primary coil in.
- Transformer primary coil out is fed to spindle neutral.

Please see photos below.

[image: gray cable to right is source, black cable to left is spindle, bottom gray cable is transformer]

- Gray cable to right is source
- Black cable to left is spindle
- Bottom gray cable is transformer

[image: Only connectors for primary stage on this side and name is "drossel" (throttle?)]

- Only connectors for primary stage on this side
- Name of this transformer is "drossel", which according to google means "throttle"

[image: No connectors here (or anywhere else for that matter)]

- No connectors here (or anywhere else for that matter)

So it appears that the transformer has only a primary coil and no secondary. In other words, it is functionally equivalent to a giant coil.

My question is, **what purpose does this transformer serve**?

My naive guess as a novice is that it is used as some kind of filter or storage, like a capacitor.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: [Autotransformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer) have only a single winding.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: but an autotransformer will have more than two connections to its single winding.

Comment: Could you please draw a schematic of the circuitry and add it to your post?

Answer (score 5):

It's choke, a.k.a. an inductor. The nameplate says 125mH 6A.

From inspecting the wiring, only two power wires go to the spindle, so it's single-phase and the inductor is in series.

Its purpose is to limit the current that can flow to the spindle motor; this limits the torque the spindle motor can develop. It also much reduces the peak current to the spindle motor when starting or stalled.

Answer (score 4):

It is also translated as [choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(electronics)).

If your motor is 3-phase then this is most likely used to create phase-shift. Kinda ad-hoc starter for asynchronous motor.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget the question, `what purpose does this transformer serve?`

Comment: @KingDuken Better? :)

Comment: When you need a high reactance small capacitors work, but when you want a low reactance (i.e the currents are fairly high), you need a big capacitance. Big capacitors are much more viable today than they were in the past, which is probably why a choke is being used when today a motor run capacitor might be.

Comment: @HenryCrun Sure, single capacitor can do the same. Although nowadays both kinds of hacking can only raise the eyebrows.

Comment: nice idea, but it's not wired that way. there only 2 power wires going to the spindle motior

Comment: Well, then it's just a choke.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of "drossels" or chokes have been used in massive C-L-C filters after standard AC rectification in old power supplies for tube-based equipment, to filter out 100 (or 120) Hz component in power rail. At that time (60-th and 70-th) there were no affordable means (linear stabilizers) for high-power supplies, so the 
massive chokes were used instead.

Comment: There are other advantages. By evening out the current demands they reduce the load on the rectifier and the transformer.

Comment: @Jasen, yep, you are right, mental blip happens, sorry. Corrected.